# Create a project section in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

i am new to Drupal and want to do the following:

1. Allow for a simple user registration process
2. Once the user is registered, allow them to register a project->a project is going to          basically have a name, an address and a picture.
3. Allow for projects to have teams within themselves

kindly guide how to proceed and modules required to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there is a core module called "Users".  That allows for username creation and authentication.  Just go to "admin/modules" and enable it.  Then take some time to familiarize yourself with how that works in terms of the experience of creating an account and managing users.

If you require additional login functionality (such as being able to log in using and email address instead of a username), there is a module called [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) that provides a lot of good functionality

For user profiles, there is a new Drupal 7 module called [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) which should meet your needs.  Just install it and its dependencies and specify which fields should be in a user profile.

For teams and projects, I think that maybe you're thinking about things the wrong way.  Look into the module [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og).  That will allow you or users to create their own teams that can then be associated with different nodes.

Finally, create a node type called Project.  Specify whatever fields you need for that project.  Then, set your permissions so that users can create groups and create new Projects.

Comment: thanks that was helpful just can you please explain a bit more about organic groups and node creation?